# A Monitor that Takes Specific Action

Tags: system-monitor

I want a monitor which *not only* reports changes, but **carries out a specified action**, when an event is triggered.

I have a few tools I am trying, but can't seem to achieve my desired goal

I'm not sure I understand how to use iwatch command.
Looking at the COMMAND LINE USAGE EXAMPLES...

```
$ iwatch -r -c (w;ps -ef)|mail -s '%f was changed' root@localhost /bin
              Monitor /bin directory, recursively, and execute the commands  'w'  and  'ps  -ef',
              sending  the  results  to  root@localhost,  using  '<path_filename> was changed' as
              subject.  To see about '%f' take a look at STRINGS FOR COMMAND section.
```

How can I **execute a command** to move or remove a file, *after an event is triggered*?

I also tried fileschanged, but apparently the file must be known, to be monitored. So the following does not work...

```
fileschanged --show=created,changed --files-to-monitor *.*
```

Is there a good program out there, which will allow me to for example, **set a command** to move a file, once it triggers an event, and if so, what's it's usage?

Comment: Is it any clearer? I'm not sure I know how to make it any clearer. Maybe someone will offer to edit it. I really don't know how to be more specific at this point.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want the monitor to listen for? A new file with a specific name? A new file, but with an unknown name? A change to an existing file? What are you trying to detect?

Comment: Watch a directory. Report when a file is created, changed, etc. Set or execute a specific command e.g. move the file to another directory. That's it.

Comment: Seems like an ordinary [systemd.path](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html) job, as described so far.

Comment: Seems you are right. Looking over the information in that link, does indicate this is what I am looking for. Makes me wonder though, why are all these other monitors being recommended, when this built in service is available. Thanks 
You can actually answer the question, so that I can mark that as the accepted answer. I think it's useful to know this, in case others missed it, like I did.